# recuperar linhas de um data frame

Tags: array, data.frame

Preciso recuperar toda a linha do DF, em um novo DF, somente quando encontro o elemento do vetor, no campo id do DF 
ids <- c(**2001586**,2007037,2012677,2020645) 
df <- t(data.frame(colnames = c("ID", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),  
                    "1" = c(2002043, 3, 04, 01, 01, 03),  
                    "2" = c(2002159, 3, 04, 01, 01, 01),  
                    "3" = c(3006166, 3, 04, 03, 02, 03),  
                    "4" = c(3006166, 3, 04, 03, 02, 03),  
                    "5" = c(3518655, 3, 04, 01, 69, 03),  
                    "6" = c(3518655, 3, 04, 01, 69, 03),  
                    "7" = c(3518655, 3, 04, 01, 69, 03),  
                    "8" = c(3968308, 1, 04, 01, 39, 03),  
                    "9" = c(5215625, 1, 04, 01, 39, 03),  
                    "10" = c(6249256, 3, 04, 03, 39, 03),  
                    "11" = c(2001586, 1, 01, 03, 05, 04),  
                    "12" = c(2001586, 1, 01, 03, 05, 04),  
                    "13" = c(2001586, 1, 01, 03, 05, 04),  
                    "14" = c(2000865, 3, 04, 03, 05, 06),  
                    "15" = c(2000865, 3, 04, 03, 05, 06),  
                    "16" = c(2000873, 3, 04, 03, 02, 03),  
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

essa função só me retorna um id do DF 
result <- as.data.frame(lapply(df[1], function(x) intersect(ids,x)))

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

result <- df[df[1]==(lapply(df[1], function(x) intersect(ids,x))),]